# php change uploaded file owner

Tags: apache2, php

I installed php5 , mysql and apache2 without any error. Everything is working fine. apache2's Root directory is /var/www (permission is 775). Problem is when i upload a file using php code it change the owner of uploaded file (as root). So i can not read this file from another code without changing owner of file manually. Is there is anyway to solve this problem? Should i add user to php group (how)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: shantanu, can you explain how you installed apache2 and php5? It will help clarify how your file was owned by root, and help us answer your question.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're running apache as root, which is generally a bad idea. ESPECIALLY when you're allowing files to be uploaded.

Comment: how can i configure it?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to change file permissions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: It is not possible to change file permission manually(not practical ). uploaded file is owned by root so it is also not possible to run chown using php.

Comment: It is actually possible to chown with PHP by specifying the right config in sudoers. BUT your files should NOT be owned by root unless the webserver is running as root, or /var/www does not really have 755 permissions. How about posting the output from `ps aux | grep apache` and `ls -la /var/www/`?